# R: How to handle a list of dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I've got a list named `rec` containing dataframes of participant1 to participant17 and should check the number of columns in every single dataframe. This is how I tried it:

```
columns = rep(NA, length(1:17))
v1 = seq(1:17)
for (i in v1) {
    columns = length(rec$participant[i])  
}
```

Unfortunately R just returns 0 for columns and I would be happy about for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Just use lapply or sapply . You will accomplish that in one line

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it!